# Enforceability of service contract liability amid consumer relocation

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, breach-of-contract, unfair-terms, enforceability

Meet Alice. She joined a gym on a 12 month contract. She moves out of the area or country and while requiring evidence of a permanent move such as a lease agreement in the new locale or employment contract, they allow her to be released from the liability and cancel the contract. Presumably not out of the goodness of their hearts but because their legal department advised them that they have to. Is that a sensible presumption? And if so, what would be the legal basis for this advice? Would it be deemed an unfair/unenforceable contract term?

Meet Bob. Bob entered a 12 month mobile phone service sum only contract binding him for 12 months. He moves out of the country making the service no longer relevant or useful to him, but the service provider does not hear any of it and insist on holding him to the contract. Is their position enforceable?

Comment: While I doubt that the lawyer did advise the gym to release the user (and instead point to the PR department), the phone service actually is useable globally... but rather expensive due to roaming outside of the own *Region* (e.g. the EU has a ban on roaming for any EU user)

Comment: The suggestion of PR department is sensible, however it should be clarified that the original idea was not that they consulted a lawyer about Bob's contract and relocation per see but rather that lawyers were involved in formulating the standard policy of the company. That being said the more I reconsider the less plausible the PR department theory seems.

Comment: In any event what if Alice is relocating outside the EU?

Comment: Realistically speaking it becomes useless due to roaming charges that are impractically and prohibitively expensive.

Comment: In relation to gym contracts, the Competition and Markets Authority investigated them and found "unfair" cancellation terms. The CMA said gym contracts should be cancellable in changes of circumstances such as serious injury or illness, job loss or moving away from the area. I'm not aware of a similar finding in relation to mobile phone contracts. 
https://www.gov.uk/government/news/gym-users-saved-37-million-by-crackdown-on-unfair-contracts. If you think a mobile phone contract term is "unfair" you can contact your local Trading Standards Office, CMA and/or perhaps Ofcom.

Comment: Is the essence of the issue not largely the same, notwithstanding that a gym is a fixed facility while a network may have roaming partnerships? Because realistically roaming is intended to be a temporary short term solution for short duration trips abroad, not to be practically efficient for permanent relocation. Is there any reason to think that despite being in a different sector the mobile phone network operators would not be treated the same way given the essentially similar issue at question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that the contract is king. It is assumed that the parties knew what they were doing when they negotiated the terms and therefore they should be binding.

In order to depart from the general rule you need to find a rule of law which allows you to do so. The applicable rule here is found at [Section 62](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/62) of the Consumer Rights Act 2015:

> (1) An unfair term of a consumer contract is not binding on the
> consumer.
>
> (4) A term is unfair if, contrary to the requirement of good faith, it
> causes a significant imbalance in the parties' rights and obligations
> under the contract to the detriment of the consumer.
>
> (5) Whether a term is fair is to be determined —
>
> (a) taking into account the nature of the subject matter of the
> contract, and
>
> (b) by reference to all the circumstances existing when the term was
> agreed and to all of the other terms of the contract or of any other
> contract on which it depends.

[Section 63(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/63) provides:

> Part 1 of Schedule 2 contains an indicative and non-exhaustive list of
> terms of consumer contracts that may be regarded as unfair for the
> purposes of this Part.

You can see the list in Part 1 of Schedule 2 [here](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/schedule/2). As noted above, this list is non-exhaustive and non-binding so both of the following are possible:

1. A term may be unfair despite not falling within any of the categories in the list.
2. A term may be fair despite falling within one of the categories albeit the fact that it is in the list is likely to be persuasive.

Turning to the examples in the question, both Alice and Bob entered into 12 month contracts which (presumably) did not have a without-cause termination clause for *either* party (i.e. in the absence of some trigger such as a breach of contract, neither party can terminate within the first 12 months). In this sense, there is no "significant imbalance in the parties' rights and obligations". Bob cannot terminate if he decides he doesn't want the contract anymore, but neither can the phone provider.

Of the Schedule 2 items, the only one which seems relevant to me is this:

> 5. A term which has the object or effect of requiring that, where the consumer decides not to conclude or perform the contract, the consumer
>    must pay the trader a disproportionately high sum in compensation or
>    for services which have not been supplied.

Perhaps Bob can argue that being made to pay the remaining monthly subscription fees is a "disproportionately high sum". Then again, considering these fees tend to be fairly low, a 12 month contract is very common across multiple different sectors and is not a very long period, and he still has the use of the phone, the term may be deemed fair.

EDIT: given Lag's [link](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/gym-users-saved-37-million-by-crackdown-on-unfair-contracts) posted in the comments, it may well be possible to argue that the following may be unfair:

1. A contract longer than 12 months which cannot be terminated.
2. A contract shorter than 12 months which cannot be terminated if you can no longer use the service e.g. by moving out of the area.

Again, this would have to be viewed in light of Section 62 which requires an analysis of the nature of the contract subject matter, and all the surrounding circumstances. It may not necessarily follow that a decision affecting gym memberships (which are useless if you move away) would be applicable to mobile phone contracts (which are useable, at least in some sense, if you move away).

Comment: What does it mean in part 1 sch. 2 where the phrase "conclude or perform" the contract is used several times? Specifically what is meant by "conclude"? Does it mean the same as "complete"? If you used and paid for mobile service for 8 months and then breached, would keeping the contract for the next 4 be what is meant by concluding the contract?

Comment: Also as noted in my comment above on the question itself, roaming provisions are not intended to be used for permanent or long term relocation but relatively short trips.

Comment: Plus if one moved to Zimbabwe for example one's phone number would still be British.

Comment: @JosephP. 1. Concluding a contract means agreeing or entering into it, e.g. after some period of negotiation. You can see a clue for this meaning in item 15 in that schedule: "*[...] price is too high in relation to the price agreed when the contract was concluded.*" 2. Agreed that your phone may be *less convenient* or *more expensive to use* after you go abroad, but you still have the use of it. You can still receive SMS and see when someone has tried to call you. In that sense it isn't quite the same as a gym membership where you can't use it at all.

Comment: @JosephP. So for example, the 2nd limb of item 5 in the schedule (*"[...] or for services which have not been supplied"*) would apply to the gym membership but not the phone contract. For the 1st limb, paying for a gym membership you cannot use at all is more likely to be a "disproportionately high sum" than paying for a phone which you can use, albeit in a more limited way.

Comment: Fine but it seems that your application of this proposed balancing exercise is quite arbitrary. I mean if we want to get arbitrary by playing devil's advocate then we can't truly say that the gym cannot be used at all either: you may still return back to your old city on weekends or for a holiday in which case you would be completely entitled and welcome to use the gym, would you not?

Comment: @JosephP. Another factor is that the mobile phone company incurs a cost by letting you out of the contract early. They tend to offer cheaper rates the longer you sign up for: they sacrifice some money in exchange for the guarantee of having your business for longer. E.g. right now [Vodafone](https://www.vodafone.co.uk/mobile/best-sim-only-deals) charge £41 per month for an unlimited tariff on a 30 day contract, £35 on a 12 month, and £25 on a 24 month. So if you sign up for 12 months and cancel after 6, you deprive them of £36 they could have charged on the 30 day contract.

Comment: @JosephP. "you may still return back to your old city on weekends or for a holiday in which case you would be completely entitled and welcome to use the gym" - Yes, that is correct. But these decisions are not all-or-nothing. The court will conduct a balancing exercise. Paying for a gym that requires you to board an international flight to use is *more* disproportionate than a phone which you can use whenever you like but in a more limited way. The rules are kept intentionally broad and vague to give the court discretion to decide what they feel is fair for the given circumstances.

Comment: @JosephP. What we can say, in the absence of being aware of any other relevant case law, is that an uncancellable gym in another geographical location *does* tip the balance into unfairness, while a phone you can only use in roaming mode *may or may* not tip the balance.

Comment: It seems straightforward to my (albeit and admittedly not professionally seasoned/calibrated) intuition that both should roughly fall into the same category despite their nuanced shades of difference.

Comment: You seem to have an (albeit decidedly conjectural/speculative and uncertain) view that the courts would be fairly likely to view them as different categories for the purposes of the balancing exercise.

Comment: Obviously neither of us could never really know until the matter is actually bright to a court but our difference in conjectural intuitive assessments is curious to me: it seems fairly straightforward that as it doesn't really make sense in practice such that most people moving countries with few exceptions will elect to get local phone service that is most likely the bar that ought to be met.

Comment: Gyms have differentiated membership rates too: if you go monthly you have to pay a joining fee and a higher monthly membership charge. If you get a 12 month contract, you not only get a lower rate but often no joining fee as well.

Comment: Sorry have only just read your two latest comments since posting my own that appear after yours. Anyway it seems that we are quite in agreement.

Comment: Okay so according to Bob's would-be mobile service provider, one can use roaming while abroad to call UK numbers but not local numbers of the new foreign locale. Further, data is limited to 25gb and he could only be away for up to 59 days in any 120 day period before it simply stops working, so some of our premises are actually incorrect.